# Can't connect to SQL Server via dart

Tags: sql-server, dart

I need to create a windows REST app that runs on a SQL Server machine, to provide data from a SQL Server database to an Android app.

I know that it would be better to create the REST app in NODE, but since I'm learning Flutter I prefer build in DART to avoid learning 2 development tools.

After some searching, I found the DART library `dart_mssql`, but I get errors when I try to run the demo example:

> c://users/xx/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_mssql-1.0.1/lib/src/sql_connection.dart:1:1:
> Error: Dart native extensions are no longer supported.
>
> Migrate to using FFI instead (https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop)
> import 'dart-ext:dart_mssql';
>
> Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies

Is there a way to avoid this incompatibility with new DART 2 version?
I tried other SQL Server Dart libraries, but none seem to work...

Comment: Though I know *nothing* of Dart, the error seems to be very informative... *"Dart native extensions are no longer supported. Migrate to using FFI instead"*

Comment: `I tried other SQL Server Dart libraries, but none seem to work`. You can draw a logical conclusion. Thus nothing helps you if you have already tried everything.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with not using node for an API. In fact it makes perfect sense to build all layers of your app in a whatever language you are comfortable with. Have you tried connecting using this method: https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket

Answer (score 0):

sql_conn (Only Device Android). Work...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).